# Reconhecer apenas a primeira letra da palavra PYTHON

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um programa conversor de temperaturas para um trabalho, e estou com uma dúvida

```
tipo_temperatura = input('Qual tipo de temperatura deseja escolher?\nCELSIUS [C]\nFAHRENHEIT [F]\nKELVIN [K]\nESCOLHA: ').strip().upper()
    if tipo_temperatura not in ['C', 'F', 'K']:
        raise ValueError('Tipo de temperatura inválido')
```

Eu queria saber qual comando terei que usar para caso o usuário digite por exemplo "Celsius", o programa reconheca que a primeira letra foi "C", e então ele não irá reconhecer como um ValueError, e sim como resposta "C", continuando o programa

Comment: Use o `startswith`, sempre retorna True se a string começa com o prefixo que definiu nesse caso mesmo que digite por extenso **FAHRENHEIT** vai pegar apenas a primeira letra. `if not tipo_temperatura.startswith(['C', 'F', 'K']):`

Comment: Se o usuário digitar `Cachorro` deve reconhecer como Celsius? Se digitar `Falcão` ser `F`? Com startswith palavras que comecem com C, F e K serão aceitas, pra resolver cheque ambos, abreviação e palavra inteira, `while True: tipo_temperatura = input('Qual tipo de temperatura?').strip().upper()
 if tipo_temperatura not in ('C', 'F', 'K', 'CELSIUS', 'FAHRENHEIT', 'KELVIN'): print('Temperatura invalida') else: <faz algo aqui>` e depois use o [***slice da string***](/a/536620/3635) nativo do Python para usar em comparações posteriores: `tipo_temperatura[0]`. Exemplo: https://ideone.com/67ECXC

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é pegando o índice zero da variável `tipo_temperatura`. Um exemplo de como fazer isso seria:

```
print(tipo_temperatura[0])
```

Uma outra maneira é utilizando a função `str.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]])` da seguinte forma:

```
tipo_temperatura.startswith(('C','F','K'))
```

Segundo a documentação

> prefixo também pode ser uma tupla de prefixos a serem procurados

Repare que neste caso o argumento `prefix` da função `startswith` é o valor `('C','F','K')` [que é a declaração de nossa tupla].

Para mais informações consulte a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str).

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que uma solução elegante pra esse problema possa ser:

```py
UNIDADES_VALIDAS = ['C', 'F', 'K']

TEXTO_DE_INPUT = '''
Qual tipo de temperatura deseja escolher?

CELSIUS [C]
FAHRENHEIT [F]
KELVIN [K]

ESCOLHA: '''


input_temperatura = input(TEXTO_DE_INPUT).strip().upper()
unidade_escolhida = input_temperatura

if len(input_temperatura) > 1:
    unidade_escolhida = input_temperatura[0]

if unidade_escolhida not in UNIDADES_VALIDAS:
    raise ValueError('Tipo de temperatura inválido')

# Agora, faça o que precisa com a variável `unidade_escolhida`
...
```